# Classes of objects c++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++ but know object oriented programming..

I have a class that has some objects of different classes.

```
class machine{
public:
    int func();
private:
    Plug p;
    std::vector<Rot> r;
    Ref ref;
};
```

Is this the correct way to do it? The reason I'm not so sure is because if I do something like `cout << this->r.size()` in `func` it doesn't output anything (I have the right includes and namespaces). The compiler compiles it but the program says `run failed`. No further messages. I'm using the latest Cygwin compiler g++ compiler.

**Edit**: I'm just trying to make sure that this is the correct way to define a member object of a class. So `Plug p;` : is that correct? Because if I call a method in the `Plug` class from within `machine`, it doesn't work like it works when I call a Plug method in `main()`. Moreover, the program exits with a fail when I do something with `r` (the `vector`)... Do I somehow have to call their constructors? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this code doesn't even compile... post your real code.

Comment: Can you paste the body of machine::func()?

Comment: To format code, instead of using `<pre>` tags, just select the block and press the `{}` button, Ctrl-K, or alternatively indent each line with 4 or 5 spaces (I just don't remember)

Comment: How are you using this class?

Comment: If it runs without error but does not output anything, then are you sure it has a place to put its output to? In other words, did you compile it as a console application - does it open a "DOS" window when it runs? Does that window stay open long enough so a human being (such as yourself) can actually see anything in it?

Comment: Yes, everything I see there is correct.  If `cout << this->r.size()` doesn't output _anything_ then: the `cout` stream is in an error state, you didn't flush, you've redirected the output, or the execution flow never got that far.

Comment: tenfour Do I have to? I just want to make sure that that's the correct way to USE objects in a class in C++.

mkb Func does nothing at the moment.

DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks! I always wondered how to do block code

BrankoDimitrijevic Output is fine. In face, if I for example output something before instantiating the class and doing anything with vector<rot> the output is fine. I'm using Netbeans for output so I can see all the output correctly (No DOS windows)

MooingDuck I'll give it a go.

Comment: I don't know if you're notified when the question is edited... So please take a look at the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on really basic C++ subjects like constructors.  When you instantiate a machine object, the constructor will be called.  In your case, a default constructor created by the compiler.  This invisible default constructor will also call the default constructors of p, r, and ref.

As for your output, try cout << r.size() << endl; to flush the buffer.  Note that you also must call x.func() in main() where x is an instance of machine.

What does your main look like?

Also, note that C++, more so than many other languages, require that you get the basics understood well - that means a lot of reading and trying examples to test your understanding.  There are many pitfalls and gotchas in this language - I wouldn't advise guessing around or assuming too much about how details in other OO languages could possibly apply to C++.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question: Yes, that is the correct way to define a data member. Each data member's constructor is called automatically, the compiler generates the necessary code for that.

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, although of course it's just an excerpt, so it's hard to say what's going wrong.

`r.size()` is actually sufficient where you have `this->r.size()`. And if you get a "run failed" error, it can't be just a missing flush to cout, but I imagine if you use a debugger it should be easy to find out what goes wrong.